# PHP site on new server can't connect after authenticating user

Tags: php, iis, windows-server-2016, mysql5.5

I'm moving an existing PHP/MySQL website application to a new server and for some reason I'm getting a "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" error after I login.

I've installed PHP and MySql and copied the database over.  I've configured the website in IIS and I can load the login page, which also does a database connection, so I know that I'm able to connect to the database and I know that PHP is working properly.

However, as soon as I enter in a username and password, it chugs for a minute before it finally tells me it can't connect.

```
This site can’t be reached
198.72.112.108 refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

That's the error I get on Chrome but I get a similar error in Firefox.

At first I thought maybe it was because it was redirecting to https and I don't have a security certificate installed yet, but that wouldn't prevent the page from loading.

I've double checked that the user privileges on the DB match exactly the old server, so I know that's good and the login page is in the same folder location as the page I'm trying to redirect to so obviously the file system privileges are good.

What could be causing this ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out I had some javascript that was redirecting to https and this was indeed the problem, although I'm not sure why it doesn't just load the page with a security warning instead.  Anyway, I disabled that code and the problem went away.